# Vim plugin to auto complete across multiple open buffers

Tags: vim, autocomplete, vim-plugin

Is there a vim plugin that does auto completion across multiple files?

Example:

- Open files are `a.txt` and `b.txt`.
- While using `vim` to edit `b.txt`, I want to be able to receive auto completion results from `a.txt` and `b.txt`

I already use the `youCompleteMe` plugin, but that only does completion in one file for methods from that language.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you need code completion for say `C++`, YCM is the way to go, but you need to configure it to do what you want. Not sure it is possible with banal `.txt` files though...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vim’s **built-in completion** with [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> in Insert Mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-N) **already supports this**. There is no need for a plug-in.

You can see that with the following test:

1. Create a file `very-basic-vimrc` with the following contents:

   ```
   set nocompatible
   filetype plugin indent on
   syntax enable
   ```
2. Run `vim -u very-basic-vimrc`. That launches Vim using that file as your `vimrc`, so you can test how Vim works without any plugins.
3. In the empty buffer, type the text “one two three”.
4. Run `:new` to open another buffer, and type “four five six”.
5. Switch back to the first buffer with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd>, then open a new line with `o`.
6. Type “fi” and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>. This triggers the next autocomplete match – see [Vim’s documentation for `i_CTRL-N`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-N). “five” will successfully be completed, even though the word “five” is in a different buffer.

If this functionality is not working for you with your normal vimrc, one of your installed plugins such as [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) might be interfering with that behavior. Change the settings for that plugin or disable it.

I personally use [Supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab). With Supertab, I can successfully type <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete a word from a different buffer. Other popular completion plugins probably support that feature too.

I see that YouCompleteMe purports to offer completion without even needing to type <kbd>Tab</kbd>. If completions from other buffers do not show up in that automatically-triggered list, YouCompleteMe probably does it on purpose so that normal typing won’t be slowed down too much. You would have to look in YCM’s documentation for an option that enables it, or a mapping that expands the completion list to include completions from other buffers. If neither of those exist, you could create an issue requesting that on [YouCompleteMe’s issue tracker](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues).

Comment: This is across buffers and not files... :/